# Running any exe with Jsch in a AWS windows server not working

Tags: jsch

We have a Windows server in AWS and we are interacting using Jsch.
We are able to write a file there. We can also execute this command:
`tasklist | findstr myprogram`
to check if *myprogram* is running and correctly see the resulting output of executing that command when *myprogram* is running or not.

The thing is that, when *myprogram* is not running, we want to launch it. And for some reason there is no way to launch any .exe remotely. I suspect we are missing something. Like in the other cases, we use an **exec** channel. We get neither output nor error, nothing. Am I missing something? There is something special with the .exe to be taken into account?
Maybe the way we write the path? Maybe the way we launch the command?

```
 cmd = "start cmd /k C:\\path\\to\\myprogram.exe";
```

Same thing happens with different exes, so is not a thing of myprogram.
Following the method used to execute the commands. The output is printed for a command like taskklist, also if you execute a command with an error, the error is correctly printed.

```
    private List<String> executeSSHCommand(String cmd, Session session) {
    try {
        channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream errorBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        InputStream err = channel.getExtInputStream();
        channel.setCommand(cmd);
        channel.connect();

        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0) break;
                outputBuffer.write(tmp, 0, i);
            }
            while (err.available() > 0) {
                int i = err.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0) break;
                errorBuffer.write(tmp, 0, i);
            }
            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                if ((in.available() > 0) || (err.available() > 0)) continue;
                System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception ee) {
            }
        }

        String output = outputBuffer.toString("UTF-8");
        String errs = errorBuffer.toString();
        System.out.println("Executing " + cmd + ": ");
        System.out.println(" - output: " + output);
        System.out.println(" - error: " + errs);
        List<String> out = new ArrayList<>();
        out.add(output);
        out.add(errs);
        return out;
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: seeing these symptoms "locally", i would (intuitively) check the [`PATH_EXT`](https://superuser.com/q/1027078/107659) OS variable.... but with "aws", "remote" and "jsch" and few infos it gets more obscure.

Comment: Did you test if this approach works at all with `ssh` (or any other SSH client) before trying to code it in Java/JSch?

Comment: My guess is, that you do not read the inputstream of the channel entirely. Please try the https://github.com/mwiede/jsch/blob/master/examples/Exec.java example and show your code to us, so that it is possible to identify the issue. For example, what exit-code do you receive?

Comment: @xerx593 Following your suggestion I checked that and EXE is there. But well, one thing discarded, thanks.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The command, exactly the same as appears in the code, works well with Putty, the program is launched. So it must be something with the code.

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann Code added. The exit code is 0. I tried this: 1) executed the tasklist | findstr to check if myprogram is running; 2) not running? then execute it, and it returns exit 0 and no errors; 3) tasklist | findstr again to check if it is really running, but no, is not running (when it is already running, I see it in the output). All this programmatically, inside the same code. Is not that I am opening a parallel session with a ssh to check if myprogram is running. But if I execute the command to launch myprogram from a ssh client, with exactly the same command of the code, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After unsuccessfully trying several combinations of start, cmd, /k, /c,... I could only make it work like this. The command is just the executable:

```
cmd = "C:\\path\\to\\myprogram.exe";
```

And now the method does not read the output or the error:

```
    private List<String> executeSSHCommandDoNoReadOutput(String cmd, Session session) {
    try {
        channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        channel.setCommand(cmd);
        channel.connect();

    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    channel.disconnect();
    return null;
}
```

Not specially happy with the workaround but is the only way I could make it work. I don't get why all the other things were not working.